# Wired dojo/domReady! behavior

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I'm learning Dojo Toolkit and ran into this wired problem about `dojo/domReady!`. I have a working example as this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script>
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
        };
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        require([
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/dom-construct',
            'dojo/domReady!'
        ], function (dom, domConstruct) {
            var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
            domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!</em>', greetingNode);
        });
    </script>
    <!-- <script src="./script.js"></script> -->
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I move the javascript code into an external file and source it before `<h1 id...</h1>` it won't work. (This is so strange that the code is working in StackOverflow's in-page HTML editor!)

```js
require([
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/dom-construct',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function (dom, domConstruct) {
    var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
    domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!</em>', greetingNode);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script>
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
        };
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./script.js"></script> <!-- this position is not OK in my local machine-->
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- <script src="./script.js"></script> --> <!-- this position is OK-->
</body>
</html>
```

But it actually didn't work on my local computer, see the screenshot:
[image] Anybody can help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I copy/pasted your two files verbatim and ran on an Apache webserver. Your example works for me. Perhaps you are running into a caching issue? And what version of Chrome?

Comment: Yes. I confirm that it was a caching issue. It works fine after I disabled the caching in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the following code in the head of you HTML file:

```
<script>
    require([
        'dojo/dom',
        'dojo/dom-construct',
        'dojo/domReady!'
    ], function (dom, domConstruct) {
        var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
        domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!</em>', greetingNode);
    });
</script>
```

Just after

```
 <script>
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
        };
    </script>
```

Basically `dojo/domReady!` will wait until the DOM has finished loading before returning and IMO was not designed to be used in the way described in your question.